# Auto add tag to product after WooCommerce purchase

Tags: php, woocommerce, tags

Is there a way to automatically apply a tag to a product in WooCommerce after it has been purchased the first time?

I've got it set up to display a "Sold Out" banner on any product with the tag "Sold". I now just need the system to auto apply that tag after purchase of that specific product (not others).

I need it done using tags (as opposed to out of stock) for a reason, as I'm using out of stock to do something different.

Please help,
-Kraig

Comment: Hook into [`woocommerce_reduce_order_stock`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#952), then use [`wp_set_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to add the tag.

Comment: Could you help me write it by chance?

Comment: Well... that's not really how Stack Overflow is supposed to work... You try writing something yourself. Do some research, narrow down what you have trouble with, then describe the specific problems you face including the code that is failing. Then someone else (could be me) help you overcome those specific problems. If you want someone to write your code *for* you, then there are other sites for that.